# EF 6.1 Fluent API: Ignore property of the base class

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I have a base class for all entities:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int SomeProperty {get; set;}
}

public class SomeEntity : BaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

I want to ignore this property in some cases. Could I do in the OnModelCreating method something like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Properties<int>()
                    .Where(p => p.Name == "SomeProperty")
                    .Ignore();
}
```

?

Comment: I suspect that would break Liskov's Substitution Principle.

Comment: How? I'm looking for the easiest way for set EF behavior based on some external conditions only. I don't want to remove property in inherits.

Comment: All I am saying is that you should think long and hard about removing a property from Entity Framework because it breaks LSP. Consider if inheritance is in fact the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>().Ignore(p => p.SomeProperty);
```

It will cause `SomeProperty` not to be mapped to `SomeEntity`.

EDIT: If this property should never be mapped to database you can add `NotMapped` annotation in your `BaseClass`:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    [NotMapped]
    public int SomeProperty {get; set;}
}
```

This will be the same as ignoring this property in all extending classes.

Comment: I know about this construction. But I have many entities and 1) I don't want to add it for every entity 2) When I create new entity I need to add another one.

Answer (score 2):

Could you override it?

```
public class SomeEntity : BaseClass
{    
    [NotMapped]
    public override int SomeProperty { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A late entry here - but in case it's useful...

Having recently encountered similar requirements, I went with this:-

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
    {
        mb.Types<EntityBase>()
          .Configure(config => config.Ignore(x => x.SomeBaseClassPropertyToIgnore));
    }
}
```

This will apply the given configuration to all entity types that inherit from EntityBase.  The same technique can be used to configure entity types based on an interface they implement (probably a better approach anyway).

Advantages are:-

- No need to write and maintain the same config code for multiple concrete entities.
- No need for [NotMapped] attribute, which is less flexible and adds potentially unwanted dependencies.

Note that the targeted types can be filtered further if necessary:-

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb)
{
    mb.Types<EntityBase>().Where(t => t != typeof(SpecialExceptionEntity)).Configure(...);
}
```

Refs:-

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn235653(v=vs.113).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn323206(v=vs.113).aspx